# MyISAM or InnoDB for social networking application

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am on a college project for a **social networking** web application. I am over with the schema design part.I am using **PHP+MySQL**. Right now I am testing the application and the tables are **MyISAMs**. But I got to know that myISAM doesn't provide **row level** locking but at table level. So I am confused whether I need to switch to **InnoDB**. I am expecting a **8:3 select v/s update** and **30 updates per second** is my threshold limit. I am relying on shared hosting server. So please help me with it. Love to hear from a Database EXPERT...

Comment: take a look at the most voted questions on `mysql` tag, you might be surprized that there are many people who solved similar tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend InnoDB engine, because it has better performance in OLTP.

MyISAM is too fast when used in non-concurrent (or low concurrent) queries.

Also you can take advantage of foreign key integrity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for that info. I am having 3 to 4 tables where I am only using SELECT,INSERT and DELETE queries(No UPDATES) do i need InnoDB for those tables too...

Comment: It depends on concurrency requirements.How many concurrent queries you expect?Will you require transaction processing? As you said, MyISAM has only table-level locking, so need to consider this also.I think social network can be very concurrent.

Comment: 30-50 concurrent queries per second, transaction processing is not an issue.

Comment: In this case, InnoDB is most suitable for you.If you want, you can create tables with MyISAM engine, test performance and then ALTER them to use InnoDB.I hope you will get better performance on InnoDB.